# $op variable for form_alter

Tags: forms, drupal

I am having a hard time using the $op variable when working with forms. It seems that the $op variable is generally part of node_api (which I haven't really used), but what about the $op variable in a form alter?

How can I make my form alter apply when the node is being edited vs. created?

Comment: What do you mean by "when the node is being edited vs. created"? Is this a webform you're talking about? Or some custom form?

Comment: @Mike Crittenden - This is a CCK node form. By created, I mean going to the path node/add/my-contnent-type as opposed to going to a node that has already been created at node/1000/edit. Of course, there is 'view' also, which doesn't show the actual form, but rather the values of the existing node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no $op variable in [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter/6). The standard way to discern a node edit from a create form is to look if the node already has a nid (node id). If it has one, you know it is an already existing one, otherwise it is still in the process of being created:

```
function yourModule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Is this a node edit/create form at all?
  if (isset($form['type']) && isset($form['#node']) && $form['type']['#value'] .'_node_form' == $form_id) {
    // Yes, is the node an already existing one?
    if (isset($form['#node']->nid)) {
      // Yes, existing node, add manipulation for node edit form
    }
    else {
      // No, new node, add manipulation for node create form
    }
  }
}
```